# How to pass environment variables from one job to another in gitlab CI?

Tags: gitlab-ci

Hi I am using gitlab artifacts to pass environment variables from one job to another

```
build-code:
  extends: .base
  stage: build
  script: . ./terraform/apply.sh
  artifacts:
    reports:
      dotenv: $CI_PROJECT_DIR/build.env

run-integration-test:
  extends: .base
  stage: integration-test
  script:
    - . ./CI/.variables
    - ./gradlew integrationTest -D$API_INVOKE_URL
  needs:
    - build-code
```

where terraform/apply.sh

```
./gradlew build -x detekt
cd terraform
terraform init
terraform validate
export WORKSPACE_NAME=test
terraform workspace select $WORKSPACE_NAME || terraform workspace new $WORKSPACE_NAME
terraform apply -var="pipeline=true" --auto-approve
export API_INVOKE_URL=$(terraform output -raw api_invoke_url)
echo "API_INVOKE_URL=$API_INVOKE_URL" >> build.env
```

When I run the CI, `build-code` succeeds but fails to upload the artifact with the following error:

WARNING: : no matching files. Ensure that the artifact path is relative to the working directory
ERROR: No files to upload.

Any ideas what might be happening here ?

Comment: Is there something in the `terraform/apply.sh` script thats creating the build.env file in the CI_PROJECT_DIR?

Comment: Try changing`dotenv: $CI_PROJECT_DIR/build.env` to `dotenv: ./build.env`

Answer (score 0):

As the error message states:

> Ensure that the artifact path is relative to the working directory

`artifacts:` paths are automatically relative to `$CI_PROJECT_DIR` so you should not include `$CI_PROJECT_DIR` in the path you specify

So to get the effect you desire, change

```yaml
dotenv: $CI_PROJECT_DIR/build.env
```

to

```yaml
dotenv: build.env
```

This should resolve the artifact upload issue.

---

If you continue to experience issues after resoling the artifact upload, you should also verify the output of your script produces the expected result and output to the `build.env` file.

Specifically, be aware this line in your `apply.sh` [can potentially fail silently](https://www.shellcheck.net/wiki/SC2155) (even if you `set -e`):

```bash
export API_INVOKE_URL=$(terraform output -raw api_invoke_url)
```

Consider verifying the contents of the `build.env` file by outputting its contents to the build log (e.g., `cat build.env`).